# Display data from Quote_item error

Tags: magento2.3, phtml, quoteitem

I have tried to display the data from **Quote_item** table in the database to file **.phtml** but it shows this error
[image: Q]

the code in **Magento/MyHistory/Block/View.php**

```
<?php
   namespace Magento\History\Block;
   class View extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
   {
   public function __constructor(
    ....
    /Magento/Checkout/Model/Cart $cart
   ....)
   {
   ...
    $cart = $cart;
   ...
  }
   public function getCartData(){
       $data = $this->cart()->create()->getCollection()- 
         >addFieldToSelect('*');
       return $data;
   }
   }
```

in **Magento/MyHistory/view/frontend/template/index.phtml** like this

```
<?php
     $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
     $orders = $objectManager->create('Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart')- 
     >getCollection();
     $orders->addFieldToSelect('*');
?>     

<table class="data table" id="test-data-table">
     <h2 style="color: red;">Your Order Detail</h2>
     <caption class="table-caption">Look at this table</caption>
     <thead>
           <tr>
              <th scope="col" class="col image">Image</th>
              <th scope="col" class="col sku">Sku</th>
              <th scope="col" class="col name">Name</th>
              <th scope="col" class="col qty">Quantity</th>
              <th scope="col" class="col created_at">Create at</th>
              <th scope="col" class="col updated_at">Update at</th>
          </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
          <?php foreach ($orders as $item): ?>
               <tr>
                   <td data-th="Title" class="col sku"><?php echo $item- 
                   >getImage(); ?></td>
                   <td data-th="Title" class="col sku"><?php echo $item- 
                   >getSku(); ?></td>
                   <td data-th="Author" class="col name"><?php echo $item- 
                   >getName(); ?></td>
                   <td data-th="Content" class="col qty"><?php echo $item- 
                   >getQty(); ?></td>
                   <td data-th="Date" class="col created_at"><?php echo 
                   $item->getCreatedAt(); ?></td>
                   <td data-th="Date" class="col updated_at"><?php echo 
                   $item->getUpdatedAt(); ?></td>
               </tr>

               <?php endforeach; ?>
          </tbody>
     </table>
```

Anyone can help me, please?

Comment: Please add the code here

Comment: please attached your code

Comment: It seems like your collection object is blank. Please check that

Comment: I do not understand it clearly. Can you explain it to me? I am new to Magento 2

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below code to get data from Quote Item

> Magento\History\Block\View.php

```
<?php
namespace Magento\History\Block;
class View extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{

    protected $cart;

    public function __constructor(
        ...
        \Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart $cart
        ...
    )
    {
        $cart = $cart;
    }

    public function getCartData(){
        $itemsCollection = $cart->getQuote()->getItemsCollection();
        // get array of all items what can be display directly
        $itemsVisible = $cart->getQuote()->getAllVisibleItems();
        // get quote items array
        $items = $cart->getQuote()->getAllItems();
        return $items;
    }
}
```

> Magento/MyHistory/view/frontend/template/index.phtm

```
<?php $cartData = $block->getCartData(); ?>
```

Now here in the Phtml you can get your data with using this $cartData variable.

Comment: It's not working for me @Ravi Soni

Comment: I have updated my answer please check now.

Comment: Sorry, @Ravi Soni, it does not display any data for me.

Comment: Now what error you get can you please mention here.

Comment: it does not display any data for me. Although I already echo the data it still displays an empty page

Answer (score 1):

Try like this :

```
<?php
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$orders = $objectManager->get('Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart');

// get quote items collection
$itemsCollection = $orders->getQuote()->getItemsCollection();

// get array of all items what can be display directly
$itemsVisible = $orders->getQuote()->getAllVisibleItems();

// get quote items array
$items = $orders->getQuote()->getAllItems();

foreach($items as $item) {
    echo 'ID: '.$item->getProductId().'<br />';
    echo 'Name: '.$item->getName().'<br />';
    echo 'Sku: '.$item->getSku().'<br />';
    echo 'Quantity: '.$item->getQty().'<br />';
    echo 'Price: '.$item->getPrice().'<br />';
    echo "<br />";            
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You get a fatol error for `->addFieldToSelect('*')` you can use `addFieldToSelect` when you inject collection model in your construct. and also you don't have to use `addFieldToSelect` you can also get data without it.

> app/code/Namespace/Modulename/Block/YourCustomBlock.php

```
<?php
namespace Namespace\Modulename\Block;

class YourCustomBlock extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{ 
    protected $_cart;
 
    protected $_checkoutSession; 
  
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart $cart,
        \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->_cart = $cart;
        $this->_checkoutSession = $checkoutSession;
  
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }
  
    public function getCart() { 
        return $this->_cart;
    }
  
    public function getCheckoutSession() {
        return $this->_checkoutSession;
    }
}
```

> Your phtml file should be like this

```
// Get all items in cart
$quote = $block->getCheckoutSession()->getQuote();
$items = $quote->getAllItems();
  
foreach($items as $item) {
    echo 'Product Id: ' . $item->getProductId() . '<br />';
    echo 'Name: ' . $item->getName() . '<br />';
    echo 'Sku: ' . $item->getSku() . '<br />';
    echo 'Quantity: ' . $item->getQty() . '<br />';
    echo 'Price: ' . $item->getPrice() . '<br />';
    echo "<br /><br />"; 
}


// Get total items and total quantity in cart
$totalItems = $quote->getItemsCount();
$totalQuantity = $quote->getItemsQty();
 
//Get subtotal and grand total price of cart
$subTotal = $quote->getSubtotal();
$grandTotal = $quote->getGrandTotal();
 
//Get billing and shipping addresses
$billingAddress = $quote->getBillingAddress();
$shippingAddress = $quote->getShippingAddress();
```

Take reference from [Get Shopping Cart Data (Items, Subtotal, Grand Total, Billing & Shipping Address) in Magento 2?](http://www.blogtreat.com/get-shopping-cart-data-items-subtotal-grand-total-billing-shipping-address-magento-2/) and [Magento 2: Get all shopping cart items, subtotal, grand total, billing & shipping address](http://blog.chapagain.com.np/magento-2-get-all-shopping-cart-items-subtotal-grand-total-billing-shipping-address/)

I hope it helps!

Comment: Thank for the answer but its display it displays this Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getQuote() on null in C:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\app\code\Magento\History\view\frontend\templates\index.phtml:3 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\lib\internal\Magento\Framework\View\TemplateEngine\Php.php(59): include() #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\lib\internal\Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template.php(270): Magento\Framework\View\TemplateEngine\Php->render(Object(Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template), 'C:/xampp/htdocs...', Array) #2

Comment: remove `var` and `generated` folder then check

Comment: check error in `var/log` file